# Wordpress sql, re-ordering array based on meta value

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress

In my wordpress functions file, I'm getting sql query results of only post IDs, then taking those IDs to create an array that I send to my page.

This works perfectly but I want to re-order it based on one of the values I generate in the array process. I have a value of 'featured' and I want to make it so that any results where featured = 1 are first in the array.

```
$myresults = $wpdb->get_results( $sqlStatement );
$ress = array();
$cnt = 0; 
$imgpath = '';
            
    if(count($myresults)>0){
        foreach ($myresults as $key => $value) {
            $id = $value->ID;
            if(get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[36]',true) !='' && get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[37]',true) != ''){
                        
                        
            $ress[$cnt]['featured']  = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_is_featured',true);
                        
            $imgpath = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id,'dailymag-featured');
              if($imgpath){
                    $ress[$cnt]['imgs'] = $imgpath;
              }else{
                $ress[$cnt]['imgs'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/fairfax-4670d9c9.jpeg';
                }                       
                $cnt++;
            }
        }
    echo json_encode($ress);
    }
```

Is there a way to simply use conditions in order to put those values first in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a function get_post_meta in an array is bad practice. I would advise first querying the database to extract data from custom fields.

However, I think there are two ways to answer your question:

1. Use 2 arrays and merge them together after iteration:

```
    $myresults = $wpdb->get_results( $sqlStatement );
    $ress1 = $ress2 = array();
    $cnt = 0; 
    $imgpath = '';
    
    if(count($myresults)>0){
        foreach ($myresults as $key => $value) {
            $id = $value->ID;
            if(get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[36]',true) !='' && get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[37]',true) != ''){
                $is_featured = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_is_featured',true);
                $imgpath = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id,'dailymag-featured');
    
                $array_name = !empty($is_featured) ? 'ress1' : 'ress2';
    
                $$array_name[$cnt]['featured']  = $is_featured;
                if($imgpath){
                    $$array_name[$cnt]['imgs'] = $imgpath;
                }else{
                    $$array_name[$cnt]['imgs'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/fairfax-4670d9c9.jpeg';
                }
                $cnt++;
            }
        }
        $ress = array_merge($ress1, $ress2);
        echo json_encode($ress);
    }
```

2. Use 2 counters:

```
    $myresults = $wpdb->get_results( $sqlStatement );
    $ress = array();
    $cnt1 = 0;
    $cnt2 = 1000000; 
    $imgpath = '';

    if(count($myresults)>0){
        foreach ($myresults as $key => $value) {
            $id = $value->ID;
            if(get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[36]',true) !='' && get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[37]',true) != ''){


                $is_featured = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_is_featured',true);
                $imgpath = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id,'dailymag-featured');

                $counter_name = !empty($is_featured) ? 'cnt1' : 'cnt2';
                $ress[$$counter_name]['featured']  = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_is_featured',true);

                $imgpath = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id,'dailymag-featured');
                if($imgpath){
                    $ress[$$counter_name]['imgs'] = $imgpath;
                }else{
                    $ress[$$counter_name]['imgs'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/fairfax-4670d9c9.jpeg';
                }
                $$counter_name++;
            }
        }
        $ress = array_values( $ress );
        echo json_encode($ress);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the 2 count option, and it does indeed work for getting them in the new array, but it doesn't seem to place the featured options at the top of the array. One thing I noticed: Is_featured may be true for many records but could be zero, I want only the ones with value of 1 at the top